# Fedex Delivery Date

Tags: soap, fedex

I'm tracking a order using SOAP API for my website to get delivery date of the ordered item through Postman , it is running successfully but I'm getting only ship date and Actual pickup date ,I need to get delivery date and transit date if possible.
Here is my code which I'm sending :

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v14="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v14">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<v14:TrackRequest>
<v14:WebAuthenticationDetail>
<v14:UserCredential>
<v14:Key>userkey</v14:Key>
<v14:Password>userpassword</v14:Password>
</v14:UserCredential>
</v14:WebAuthenticationDetail>
<v14:ClientDetail>
<v14:AccountNumber>user account number</v14:AccountNumber>
<v14:MeterNumber>meter number</v14:MeterNumber>
</v14:ClientDetail>
<v14:TransactionDetail>
<v14:CustomerTransactionId>Track By 
Number_v14</v14:CustomerTransactionId>
<v14:Localization>
<v14:LanguageCode>EN</v14:LanguageCode>
<v14:LocaleCode>US</v14:LocaleCode>
</v14:Localization>
</v14:TransactionDetail>
<v14:Version>
<v14:ServiceId>trck</v14:ServiceId>
<v14:Major>14</v14:Major>
<v14:Intermediate>0</v14:Intermediate>
<v14:Minor>0</v14:Minor>
</v14:Version>
<v14:SelectionDetails>
<v14:CarrierCode>FDXE</v14:CarrierCode>
<v14:PackageIdentifier>
<v14:Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</v14:Type>
<v14:Value>trackingnumber</v14:Value>
</v14:PackageIdentifier>
<v14:ShipmentAccountNumber/>
<v14:SecureSpodAccount/>
<v14:Destination>
<v14:GeographicCoordinates/>
</v14:Destination>
</v14:SelectionDetails>
<v14:ProcessingOptions>INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS</v14:ProcessingOptions>
</v14:TrackRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and in response I'm getting this :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP- 
ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<TrackReply xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v14">
<HighestSeverity>SUCCESS</HighestSeverity>
<Notifications>
<Severity>SUCCESS</Severity>
<Source>trck</Source>
<Code>0</Code>
<Message>Request was successfully processed.</Message>
<LocalizedMessage>Request was successfully processed.</LocalizedMessage>
</Notifications>
<TransactionDetail>
<CustomerTransactionId>Track By Number_v14</CustomerTransactionId>
<Localization>
<LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
<LocaleCode>US</LocaleCode>
</Localization>
        </TransactionDetail>
        <Version>
            <ServiceId>trck</ServiceId>
            <Major>14</Major>
            <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
            <Minor>0</Minor>
        </Version>
        <CompletedTrackDetails>
            <HighestSeverity>SUCCESS</HighestSeverity>
            <Notifications>
                <Severity>SUCCESS</Severity>
                <Source>trck</Source>
                <Code>0</Code>
                <Message>Request was successfully processed.</Message>
                <LocalizedMessage>Request was successfully processed.</LocalizedMessage>
            </Notifications>
            <DuplicateWaybill>false</DuplicateWaybill>
            <MoreData>false</MoreData>
            <TrackDetailsCount>0</TrackDetailsCount>
            <TrackDetails>
                <Notification>
                    <Severity>SUCCESS</Severity>
                    <Source>trck</Source>
                    <Code>0</Code>
                    <Message>Request was successfully processed.</Message>
                    <LocalizedMessage>Request was successfully processed.</LocalizedMessage>
                </Notification>
                <TrackingNumber>trackingnumber</TrackingNumber>
                <TrackingNumberUniqueIdentifier>uniquetrackingnumberFDEG</TrackingNumberUniqueIdentifier>
                <StatusDetail>
                    <Location>
                        <Residential>false</Residential>
                    </Location>
                </StatusDetail>
                <CarrierCode>FDXG</CarrierCode>
                <OperatingCompanyOrCarrierDescription>FedEx Ground</OperatingCompanyOrCarrierDescription>
                <Service>
                    <Type>FEDEX_GROUND</Type>
                </Service>
                <PackageSequenceNumber>0</PackageSequenceNumber>
                <PackageCount>0</PackageCount>
                <DatesOrTimes>
                    <Type>ACTUAL_PICKUP</Type>
                    <DateOrTimestamp>2018-02-01T00:00:00</DateOrTimestamp>
                </DatesOrTimes>
                <DatesOrTimes>
                    <Type>SHIP</Type>
                    <DateOrTimestamp>2018-02-01T00:00:00</DateOrTimestamp>
                </DatesOrTimes>
                <DeliveryAttempts>0</DeliveryAttempts>
                <TotalUniqueAddressCountInConsolidation>0</TotalUniqueAddressCountInConsolidation>
                <DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                    <Option>INDIRECT_SIGNATURE_RELEASE</Option>
                    <Eligibility>INELIGIBLE</Eligibility>
                </DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                <DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                    <Option>REDIRECT_TO_HOLD_AT_LOCATION</Option>
                    <Eligibility>INELIGIBLE</Eligibility>
                </DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                <DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                    <Option>REROUTE</Option>
                    <Eligibility>INELIGIBLE</Eligibility>
                </DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                <DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
                    <Option>RESCHEDULE</Option>
                    <Eligibility>INELIGIBLE</Eligibility>
                </DeliveryOptionEligibilityDetails>
            </TrackDetails>
        </CompletedTrackDetails>
    </TrackReply>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Notes:- I'm passing no headers since in fedex documentation ,nothing is mention about them.